# Pass data from a component to a module in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to pass a data from one component to its module. I need the data from the component to use it in the module. I have a tab1.component.ts that has a tab.module.ts. In the tab.module.ts I have a configuration that needs to be setup that has a value that would come from the tab1.component.ts like this:

**tab1.module.ts**

```
export function createConfig(): SignalRConfiguration {
  const config = new SignalRConfiguration();
  config.hubName = 'ServerHub';
  config.qs = { user: 'Lane' };
  config.url = ???';  <==== I NEED THE DATA HERE. IT SHOULD COME FROM THE COMPONENT
  config.executeEventsInZone = true;
  config.executeErrorsInZone = false;
  config.executeStatusChangeInZone = true;
  return config;
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    SignalRModule.forRoot(createConfig),
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: Tab1Page }])
  ],
  declarations: [Tab1Page]
})
export class Tab1PageModule {}
```

**tab1.component.ts**

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm){
    if(!form.valid) {
      return;
    }
    this.ipAddress = form.value;
    console.log(this.ipAddress); <=== I NEED THIS IN THE MODULE ABOVE
    this.cs.startConnection();
  }
```